# Fastest way to get all first-matched rows given a sequence of column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

Say I have a Pandas dataframe with 10 rows and 2 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,4,3,1,3,1,5,1,4],
                   'col2': [.9,.7,.1,.3,.2,.4,.8,.2,.3,.5]})
df

   col1  col2
0     1   0.9
1     2   0.7
2     4   0.1
3     3   0.3
4     1   0.2
5     3   0.4
6     1   0.8
7     5   0.2
8     1   0.3
9     4   0.5
```

Now that I am given a sequence of `'col1'` values in a numpy array：

```
import numpy as np
nums = np.array([3,1,2])
```

I want to find the rows that have the **first occurence** of 3, 1 and 2 in `'col1'`, and then get the corresponding `'col2'` values **in order**. Right now I am using a list comprehension:

```
res = np.array([df[df['col1']==n].reset_index(drop=True).at[0,'col2'] for n in nums])
res

[0.3 0.9 0.7]
```

This works for small dataframes, but becomes the bottleneck of my code as I have a huge dataframe of more than 30,000 rows and is often given long sequences of column values (> 3,000). I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Perhaps faster than what I suggested earlier (below: *option 2*):

```
df.groupby('col1').first().reindex(nums)

      col2
col1      
3      0.3
1      0.9
2      0.7
```

**Option 2**

- First get the matches for `col1` by using [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and select from the `df` based on the mask.
- Now, apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get the [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) non-null entry for each group.
- Finally, apply [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to sort the values.

```
df[df['col1'].isin(nums)].groupby('col1').first().reindex(nums)

      col2
col1      
3      0.3
1      0.9
2      0.7
```

If a value cannot be found, you'll end up with a `NaN`. E.g.

```
df.iloc[1,0] = 6 # there's no '2' in `col1` anymore
df[df['col1'].isin(nums)].groupby('col1').first().reindex(nums)

      col2
col1      
3      0.3
1      0.9
2      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, alternate solution (might not be optimal, but) can be think as follows:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='col1', keep='first')
  .merge(df1, how='inner', on='col1')
  .set_index('col1')
  .reindex(nums)

    col2
col1    
3   0.3
1   0.9
2   0.7
```